# Generate dates from start date to end date

Tags: powerbi

I need to generate the dates from start date and end date. For example, Start date is 11th March 2022 and the end date is 11th March 2023.

I have been able to generate the dates from 11th March 2022 to 1st March 2023 using the below formula in power query

```
let 
StDt = [#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"],
AllDates = {Number.From([#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"])..Number.From([#"Vesting end date (each period)"])},

StofMonthDates = 
List.Distinct(List.Select(List.InsertRange(List.Transform(AllDates, each Date.StartOfMonth(Date.From(_))),0,{[#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"]}),each Number.From (_) >= Number.From(StDt)))
in
StofMonthDates
```

In the above query, Grant date means start date and Vesting end date means end date. I need to get the date as on the end date i.e., 11th March 2023 and not only the start of the month i.e., 1st March 2023

Answer (score 0):

In `Add Column` section ,choose `Custom Column` and use following formula where `Number.From` transform your date column to its Corresponding number

```
={ Number.From([Start_Date])..Number.From([End_Date]) }
```

it generate numbers, then you should your numbers to date.